Alarm manager but it should only work when the app is being used
I've worked with AlarmManager before but I only use it for when I want to run a code that is time specific when the app is not being used. Is there a way to create an AlarmManager that runs a code when the app is being used but it should stop when the app is closed?
I want it to run every five seconds or so if possible (one minute is the lowest that I know), and I can't find any tutorials online to help me. Thank you!

I think what you need to do is moniter the active activities and count the currently active activities. Whenever an activity is being destroyed, check the count and remove the scheduled AlarmManager if it was the last active activity (don't forget to reschedule it through your Application class). That way, the AlarmManager will stay active only while the App is being used.

Use ProcessLifecycleOwner to find out when your UI is in the foreground or not. Use ScheduledExecutorService or something tied to your preferred reactive framework (RxJava, Flow in Kotlin, etc.) to get control every five seconds. Do all that from some singleton, ideally set up by your dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).
